# Struggling to print out a 3d array

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix

```
private int[][][] puzzleBoard = new int[][][] {  

        {   {5,3,0,  0,7,0,  0,0,0},
            {6,0,0,  1,9,5,  0,0,0},
            {0,9,8,  0,0,0,  0,6,0},

            {8,0,0,  0,6,0,  0,0,3},
            {4,0,0,  8,0,3,  0,0,1},
            {7,0,0,  0,2,0,  0,0,6},

            {0,6,0,  0,0,0,  2,8,0},
            {0,0,0,  4,1,9,  0,0,5},
            {0,0,0,  0,8,0,  0,7,9},
        }
};

public void printArray() {

    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++){
          for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++){
                  System.out.print(Arrays.toString(puzzleBoard[a][b]));
                  System.out.println();
                  }
           }

    }
```

I need help in changing this array so that it will print out like a sudoku puzzle. Please help me!

Comment: What you have there is really a 2-D array that has been embedded (unnecessarily) in a another array.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  What you have there is really a 2-D array that has been embedded (unnecessarily?) in a another array.

A Soduku is really a 2-D 9x9 puzzle, not a 3-D puzzle.

> how can i fix this?

**Hint:** Either turn it into a *real* 2-D array, or just "select" and print the 2-D subarray.

Remember a 3-D array in Java is equivalent to a 1-D array of 2-D arrays.

Comment: If that's the answer, then don't forget to click the tick under the upvote/ downvote to let people know the question's been answered :)